# Order users by number of posts

Tags: custom-post-types

Im trying to order by post_count DESC but custom_post_type not working

```
function post_count_type($role, $number) {
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => array( 'custom_post_type' ),
    'orderby'       => 'post_count',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'role'          => $role,
    'number'        => $number
);
$users = get_users( $args );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo 'html here...';
    }}
```

My function work for post_type : POST but not for custom post_type.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: What is `post_count`? Each post should equate to 1 post, categories would have multiple posts assigned to there where a `post_count` would make sense. Would you happen to mean the order that you can assign under Page Attributes metabox?

Comment: The post_count is for user. I want order user by whoever posted the most article on custom_post_type. Again sorry for my english hope you understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You are using wrong approach**

You are using the wrong approach for what you are trying to achieve. You are using the same arguments for both `WP_Query` and `WP_User_Query` (`get_users` eventually translates to `WP_User_Query`). The problem is that `WP_Query` doesn't support `orderby` parameter `post_count` as one post is always equal to one post and `WP_User_Query` doesn't support `post_type` as the user doesn't have post type assigned to themselves.

**This can't be achieved using standard functions**

In `WP_User_Query` it's hardcoded that for user posts count, it looks only for post_type  `post`. To achieve what you are trying to, you need to write a custom database query.

**A custom solution**

A standalone function to achieve this might look like this (please note I haven't tested it so there might be a SQL typos or smth).

```
function get_users_by_post_count( $post_type = 'post' ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $users = $wpdb->get_results(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT {$wpdb->users}.ID, p.post_count
            FROM {$wpdb->users}  
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT post_author, COUNT(*) AS post_count 
                FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type = %s
                GROUP BY post_author
            ) p ON {$wpdb->users}.id = p.post_author 
            ORDER BY p.post_count",
            $post_type
        )
    );

    return $users;
}
```

To use it simply call it like:

```
$users = get_users_by_post_count( 'custom_post_type' );

if ( ! empty( $users ) ) {
   foreach ( $users as $user ) {
       // there you have user ID and post_count
       echo $user->ID . ' has ' . $user->post_count . ' posts';
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a core bug (at least from a first look) to have hardcoded `get_posts_by_author_sql( 'post' );` when ordering by `post_count`, since the post type should be adjustable via the `has_published_posts` (and `blog_id` non-zero). ps: there seems to be missing `return $users;` in `get_users_by_post_count()`. Adding a limit would be recommended for large number of users.

Comment: Thanks @birgire I've updated the function to return the result. Yes, it's impossible due to hardcoded post type in `get_posts_by_author_sql` it's an easy fix and I'm going to open a ticket in WP community to get it solved (never did this before, su can't guarantee it will be successful :) )

Comment: Sounds good, would be nice to have the ticket # posted  here ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped me. Have a nice day 

Comment: @birgire long time no see, haha. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/49418

Comment: This is perfect, worked 100% 4 years later!